# sudo: command not found on MacOS Sierra

Tags: macos, bash

Whenever I try to install something using sudo I get this error `-bash: sudo: command not found`
If I do `echo $PATH` it returns `/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:’/usr/local/bin:??`
I haven't been able to find any solutions online.

Comment: Sierra's `sudo` is located in `/usr/bin`; that seems to be missing from your path.

Comment: Did you modify your shell profile to override the path? Or did you even modify some system files? (What are you trying to install with `sudo`?)

Comment: Seriously? Your PATH is `/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:’/usr/local/bin:??` ? Can you run *anything* ?

Comment: @lungj how do I put it into the path?

Comment: @slhck How do I modify the shell profile?

Comment: @Scott I don't know I have never used bash before

Comment: There's a file in your home directory named `.bash_profile`; you can edit the line that starts with `export PATH=`

Comment: So you've never used the Terminal on your Mac and the system is that broken? Do you remember having changed anything? Installed anything? What were you trying to do in the first place?

Comment: @slhck How is it broken? I tried fixes I found online including deleting a few lines in the bash after entering a command, I don't remember what the command was. That could be why.

Comment: I have the same problem (sudo command not found) when I run echo $PATH I get /usr/bin:/bin/usr/sbin:/sbin
I don't know if it's right or wrong
I tried the answer above but again to type sudo vi . Bash_profile, sudo command is not found
Can you please help me make sudo command work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a temporary solution, run this command:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/opt/x11/bin:$PATH
```

Then do `sudo vi .bash_profile` and place `/usr/bin` at the end of what's already there. Press <kbd>I</kbd> in order to begin editing the document, <kbd>Esc</kbd> to stop, and type `:x` to save and quit the editor.

However, you aren't able to use `apt-get` or `yum` on a macOS system. The closest macOS has is [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) or [Macports](http://macports.org).